# show play icon on image hover

Tags: html, css

Goal: When I hover on "item" image, I want a "play" image to appear in center of "item" image div. I did following:

play.img overlaps itemImage.img

HTML:

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <img src="/images/G1.jpg"/>
  <div class="playy">
    <img src="/images/playy.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="itemsContainer">
  <img src="/images/B1.jpg"/>
  <div class="playy">
    <img src="/images/playy.png"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="clear">
```

CSS

```
.itemsContainer {
  float: left;
  width : 300px;
  height : 300px;
  margin-left : 2px;
}

.itemsContainer img {
  width : 300px;
  height : 175px;
  margin-bottom : -115px;
  z-index : -1;
}
.play img {
  position : relative;
  width : 50px;
  height : 50px;
  z-index : 100;
  margin : 0 0 50px 125px;
  opacity : 0.0 ;
} 

.itemsContainer img:hover {
  opacity : 0.8;
}
```

With code above, the "play" image appears only when I hover on div.play instead I want the "play" image to appear when I hover on .itemContainer.img

How can I make "play" image appear by hovering on itemImage.img??

Reference: http://www.itsalif.info/content/show-play-icon-mouse-over-thumbnail-using-css

for some reason I do not want to use "a" tag and I also wanted to know what I am doing wrong?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/e6Lav/5/   -- Problem
http://jsfiddle.net/2uJKR/11/  -- Solution
```

Comment: you can use cursor property of css

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="itemsContainer">
    <div class="image"> <a href="#">  <img src="#" /> </a></div>
    <div class="play"><img src="#" /> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.itemsContainer {
    background:red; 
    float:left;
    position:relative
}
.itemsContainer:hover .play{display:block}
.play{
  position : absolute;
    display:none;
    top:20%; 
    width:40px;
    margin:0 auto; left:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:100
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twfJh/2/)**

Comment: @Sowmya...thanks for quick response. Can u fix this for me w/o major changes....http://jsfiddle.net/e6Lav/5/ just asking

Answer (score 1):

The CSS is fine bot this HTML might be better

`<div class="itemsContainer">
    <a href=""><img src=""/></a> 
    <div class="play">
        <a href=""><img src="" /></a>
    </div>
</div>`

This will help the play button to be a link too :)

Comment: Bette to use the play icon as background and close </a> after that div.