# Getting an icon on an image on hover CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover, icons

I cannot get the entire icon on the right part of the image when hovering.
(this table is inside an image gallery)

This is what I should get:

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
.text-wrapper:hover {
  background: rgb(112, 88, 42);
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.image-cell:hover {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<a class="gallery-item" href="#"><img src="../images/04.jpg" alt="paper" style="width:20%"><span class="text-wrapper">
    <span class="name">
   
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td class="portfolio-cell">
      <div class="value">portfolio text</div>
    </td>
    <td class="image-cell">
      <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg"></i>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <div class="">text2</div>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [show play icon on image hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889028/show-play-icon-on-image-hover)

Comment: Any reason for usng a table? doesn't look like tabular data - you shouldn't be using tables for layout

Comment: I used a table in order to get the icon and the text side by side. Maybe a float: right; would have been a better idea, I tried without any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't nedd use `float: left/right` or tables to create that component for you layout. You can use flexbox, simple and powerful, read more about this.

And you case - you can add icon with `:after` pseudo element. Simple example https://jsfiddle.net/ruoazom7/11/